# Reversing a given array and adding to it to given array using python

Tags: python

Given an array A of N numbers, you have to write a program which prints the sum of the elements of array A with the corresponding elements of the reverse of array A.
If array A has elements `[1,2,3]`, then reverse of the array A will be [3,2,1] and the resultant array should be `[4,4,4]`.

Input Format:

The first line of the input contains a number N representing the number of elements in array A.
The second line of the input contains N numbers separated by a space. (after the last elements, there is no space)

Output Format:

Print the resultant array elements separated by a space. (no space after the last element)

Example:

Input:

```
4
2 5 3 1
```

Output:

```
3883
```

Comment: So any ideas on your side? Any code?

Comment: Is it your homework ? :)

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve along with https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (section about homework)

Comment: Hi Sreya, please take a look on this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reformulate your question.

Comment: Look into list comprehensions, `zip(...)` and `print(end = " ")`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. take input
2. parse input to a list
3. reverse the list and put a new list
4. using zip function and + operation create the final list
5. Parse the final list to get rid of ',' and '[]'

   L = raw_input()
   L = map(int, L.split())
   R = L[::-1]

   S = [x + y for x, y in zip(L, R)]

   print ' '.join(map(str, S))

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())

list1 = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))[:n]

list2 = list1[::-1]

sum_list = []

for (item1, item2) in zip(list1, list2):

    sum_list.append(item1+item2)

print(*sum_list, sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

you just reverse the list using slicing method and use it with zip in a for loop like this.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
result = []
for i, j in zip(arr, arr[::-1]):
    print (i, j)
    result.append(i+j)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
size = int(input())
list1 = []

for x in input().split():
    num = int(x)
    list1 = list1 + [num]

for i in range(math.ceil(size/2)):
    list1[i] = list1[size -1 -i] = list1[i] + list1[size -1 -i]

for i in range(size-1):
    print(list1[i], end=" ")

print(list1[size-1], end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear the console
2. Asks for user input as a list
3. Prints the List and the Reversed List
4. Initialize  the sumList
5. Use python ZIP function to iterate through the list and the reversed list, and adding their sum.

Please note: The entered values were treated as strings hence the conversion to int.

```
import os
os.system('clear')

numList = input("Enter an array/list separated by space : ").split(" ")
print (numList)
print (numList[::-1])

sumList = list()

sumList = [int(x)+int(y) for x,y in zip(numList, numList[::-1])]

print(sumList)
print("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N=int(input())
A=list(map(int,input().split()))
s=[]
for i in range(N):
  s.append(A[i]+A[N-i-1])
print (*s,end="")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!